# Сортировка даты в структуре (CИ)

Tags: c, сортировка, структуры

Есть данные в файле, их надо отсортировать по дате по возрастанию. Написал такой гкод:

```
int expFirstYear=0,expSecondYear=0;
    int i =0,j=0;
    for(i = 0; i< 30;i++){
        expFirstYear = 0;
        expFirstYear += ((int)games[i].data[6]-48)*1000;
        expFirstYear += ((int)games[i].data[7]-48)*100;
        expFirstYear += ((int)games[i].data[8]-48)*10;
        expFirstYear += ((int)games[i].data[9]-48);
        expFirstYear *=365;
        expFirstYear += (((int)games[i].data[3]-48)*10 + ((int)games[i].data[4]-48))*30;
        expFirstYear += ((int)games[i].data[0]-48)*10;
        expFirstYear += ((int)games[i].data[1]-48);

        for(j = 0; j < 30; j++){
            expSecondYear = 0;
            expSecondYear += ((int)games[j].data[6]-48)*1000;
            expSecondYear += ((int)games[j].data[7]-48)*100;
            expSecondYear += ((int)games[j].data[8]-48)*10;
            expSecondYear += ((int)games[j].data[9]-48);
            expSecondYear *=365;
            expSecondYear += (((int)games[i].data[3]-48)*10 + ((int)games[i].data[4]-48))*30;
            expSecondYear += ((int)games[j].data[0]-48)*10;
            expSecondYear += ((int)games[j].data[1]-48);

            if(expFirstYear < expSecondYear){
                temp = games[i];
                games[i] = games[j];
                games[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Первые записи оно норм сортирует, а остальные как попало.

P.S Структура:

```
struct game{
    int serNum;
    char name[20];
    int version;
    char autor[20];
    char data[13];
    int oc;
}games[30],temp;
```

Comment: Копипаста - плохо, перенесите вычисление даты в отдельную функцию.

Comment: И если у вас там дата в формате с разделителями и разделители точно    есть и data[10] не цифровой символ, то дату в числовом виде можно посчитать `atoi(games[i].data+6)*10000+atoi(games[i].data+3)*100+atoi(games[i].data)`. Вынесите расчет даты в отдельную функцию как предлагают выше, переведите расчет на мое предложение и проверьте. Если вопросы останутся - поправьте тут код и будем смотреть дальше. А вообще полное копирование структур - это катастрофа, изучите указатели и пользуйтесь. Ну и про алгоритмы сортировки почитайте

Comment: @Mike Сортирует через раз

Comment: Т.е. вы уже поправили код и он продолжил сортировать как попало ? Ну так выложите сюда код, который получился

Comment: Просто в вашем способе формирования даты явная ошибка, вы месяцы умножаете на 30, а дней все таки 31, вам может немного не хватить ...

Comment: @Mike `void sortByData(){
 int expFirstYear=0,expSecondYear=0;
 int i =0,j=0;
 for(i = 0; i< 30;i++){
  expFirstYear = atoi(games[i].data+6)*10000+atoi(games[i].data+3)*100+atoi(games[i].data);

  for(j = 0; j < 30; j++){
   expSecondYear = atoi(games[j].data+6)*10000+atoi(games[j].data+3)*100+atoi(games[j].data);
   
   if(expFirstYear < expSecondYear){
    temp = games[i];
    games[i] = games[j];
    games[j] = temp;
   }
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Да вы изначальный вопрос поправьте, что бы людям было удобнее смотреть. И заодно положите туда пример неправильной сортировки

Comment: @Mike можете объяснить как вы здесь дату переводите? atoi(games[i].data+6)*10000+atoi(games[i].data+3)*100+atoi(games[i].data)

Comment: @makintosh atoi делает int из числа в строке, причем работает до первого не цифрового символа (т.е. до разделителя который у вас в строке даты стоит между частями). на вход подается указатель на строку. data+6 значит то же что &data[6] т.е. адрес строки где лежит нужное нам число. Ну собственно и все, получаем год*10000+месяц*100+день

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! А не подскажете зачем множить? Просто я в этих переводах полный ноль.

Comment: @makintosh скажем у нас есть 2000 год, и две даты в нем 1 декабря и 20 февраля, если мы просто сложим цифры, то 1 декабря будет 2000+12+1=2013, а 20 февраля 2000+2+20=2022 и тогда выйдет, что 20 февраля больше чем 1 декабря, что по календарю явно не так. Зато если мы умножаем 2000*10000+2*100+20=20000220 ну и декабрь 20001201. все числа на своих позициях в дате и 1 декабря > 20 февраля. Собственно мы добились бы тех же самых чисел, если бы просто выбросили разделители из даты и потом применили atoi, но сдвигать их в строке imho более напряжно